# Migrate visual studio team services to tfs

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

I'd like to know if it's possible to migrate from a Visual Studio Team Services to a local Team Foundation Server. I've seen many questions about the reveser process but not this.

I know I can download source code from VSTS and upload it manually to TFS, but I'd like to keep as many work items and project structure as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), it may have some errors but can work. Refer to this link for details: [Migrate VSO to on premises TFS](http://geekswithblogs.net/henricson/archive/2015/10/18/team-foundation-server.aspx).

Comment: I was trying to follow up the link you provide but there is no information about how to configure TFS Integration Platform with a proxy, so I'm not able to connect to the Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: Then the alternative way would be get and upload the source code manually. And use Execl to export and import the work items. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel